# pyspark dataframe is saved in s3 bucket with junk data

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark

While trying to save pyspark DataFrame to csv and trying to s3 bucket directly,
file is getting saved but it has junk data. and all file sizes are 1B.
please help me where iam doing wrong.

python code

```
df.write.options("header","true").csv("s3a://example/csv")
```

trying this code also

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("path", "s3://example/test.csv").save()
```

But not getting proper csv in s3 bucket

junk data in csv file
[image]

Comment: can you elaborate on the data a bit? I'm unable to understand the junk data part.

Comment: note that spark will create a folder named `test.csv` within which will be csv part files or a collated one in case of `coalesce()`. the file name would make it seem like it is junk data. However, it is just a naming convention that spark uses. the contents within the file(s) would be per your dataframe.

Comment: are the source and target systems' encoding same? check [spark csv encoding](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saving your dataframe as `parquet` which is the default.

```
df.write.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
  .option("path", "s3a://example/csv")
  .save()
```

Note: The syntax is also `option` not `options`.

*update* 
As @Samkart mentioned you should check if your encoding is correct. I have updated my answer to include the `encoding` option. You can check [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.encode.html) for the encoding options in pyspark.

Comment: tried this but issue is same like getting junk data in s3bucket csv